# nutch Unable to successfully parse content

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I try to crawl using nutch 1.4 , but I'm facing error in parsing, this is the log file:

```
2012-01-09 09:12:02,696 INFO  parse.ParseSegment - ParseSegment: starting at          2012-01-09 09:12:02 
2012-01-09 09:12:02,697 INFO  parse.ParseSegment - ParseSegment: segment: crawl/segments/20120109091153
2012-01-09 09:12:03,416 WARN  parse.ParseUtil - Unable to successfully parse content http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/ of type application/xhtml+xml
2012-01-09 09:12:03,417 INFO  parse.ParseSegment - Parsing: http:// sujitpal.blogspot.com/
2012-01-09 09:12:03,418 WARN  parse.ParseSegment - Error parsing: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/: failed(2,200): org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseException: Unable to successfully parse content
2012-01-09 09:12:03,419 INFO  crawl.SignatureFactory - Using Signature impl: org.apache.nutch.crawl.MD5Signature
```

by checking config/nutch-site.xml I found html|text|xhtml|xml are included in the plugin.includes preperty

```
<property>
<name>plugin.includes</name>
<value>myplugins|protocol-httpclient|query-(basic|site|url)|summary- 
basic|urlfilter-    
regex|parse-(xml|xhtml|html|tika|text|js)|index-(basic|anchor)|scoring-  
opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)
</value>
<description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
include.  Any plugin not matching this expression is excluded.
In any case you need at least include the nutch-extensionpoints plugin. By
default Nutch includes crawling just HTML and plain text via HTTP,
and basic indexing and search plugins. In order to use HTTPS please enable 
protocol-httpclient, but be aware of possible intermittent problems with the 
underlying commons-httpclient library.
</description>
</property>
```

Why can't it parse xhtml/xml or even text/xml?

Answer (score 1):

Which plugins have you configured? If you are using tika, then tika has a mapping from mime-type like xhtml/xml to a parser. If there is no entry in the configfile, nothing happens.

You could disable tika and only use the parse-html plugin.

I tested your site with our default plugin config.

```
protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html)|index-(basic|anchor)
|query-    (basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)
|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-     
(pass|regex|basic)
```

And got your page parsed.

```
Parsed (32ms):http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/
```

Grettings
JPee